# how to dropdown option keep selected after page loads onchange

Tags: php, jquery, onchange, pageload

how i can get dropdown option keep selected after loading a page with function onchange? currently i can just load the page according to selected value from my dropdown. and after loading page it's selected with first value be default.

```
<select id="extDropDown">
        <option>Select Extension</option>
        <option value="*">All</option>
        <option value="zip">ZIP</option>
        <option value="rar">RAR</option>
        <option value="php">PHP</option>
        <option value="html">HTML</option>
        <option value="htm">HTM</option>
        <option value="jpg">JPG</option>
        <option value="bmp">BMP</option>
        <option value="txt">TEXT</option>
        <option value="docs">DOCS</option>
        <option value="xlsx">XLSX</option>
        <option value="xls">XLS</option>
    </select>


$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '#extDropDown' ).bind( 'change', function( e ){
    document.location.href = "?dir=<?php echo $dir; ?>&action=loadfiles&ftype=" + $( this ).val();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using JQuery, you can do this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // pre-select the existing choice (if any)
  $( '#extDropDown' ).val( '<?php echo $ftype; ?>');

  // now register further changes to the dropdown option
  $( '#extDropDown' ).bind( 'change', function( e ){
    document.location.href = "?dir=<?php echo $dir; ?>&action=loadfiles&ftype=" + $( this ).val();
  });
});
```

**Update**
Fixed typo

Comment: // pre-select the existing choice (if any)
  $( '#extDropDown' ).value( '<?php echo $ftype; ?>');

this worked for me, but i needed to change $( '#extDropDown' ).value() to val() to avoid the error. Thanks for your Help. i appreciate.

Comment: yes, typo on my part, I'll edit it for correctness for future reference